# Microsoft Interop.Word - Ignore Printer Settings When Changing PaperSize

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

I'm changing the PaperSize property of the document to A3. The currently connected printer can only print A4 so Word isn't allowing me to set the paper size bigger.

Is there a way to ignore this error and have the paper size changed anyway? I'm not wanting to print, just create a Word document of this size.

Thanks

Comment: The selected printer matters a lot to Word since it affects *everything*.  Just pick another printer, most any machine has the XPS Document Writer installed.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant changing the printer to be "XPS Document Writer" does the job for me. Simple solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @HansPassant changing the printer to be "XPS Document Writer" solved the problem for me.